# How do i limit the 'click' area?

Tags: jquery, html, css, interaction

I've got a structure like an accordion. I got 'work' divs, which i did hide some pictures inside, and i want them to work as a gallery.

So when i click on a 'work' div, the div animates and it height expands and gallery appears.

But wherever i click it just Closes the 'work' div again. So what i want to do is, i limit this click area and prevent to close the 'work' so that users can navigate through images.

I Hope i made myself clear.

Here's the image url, as you see, the work with the images underneath is an open work, but when i click on an image, it closes itself up. I arranged the 'gallery' div's z-index to 9999 but still the click is called by 'work'

http://cl.ly/image/2y3V052T0U43

Thanks in advance,
Cheers,
Met.

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: Can we see some code? Or a jsfiddle of what you've done so far?

Comment: set the z-index of the work div to be greater than the z-index of the accordian div when it shows.  that will cause the click event to be consumed by the work div and not the accordian div

Comment: Also www.metinsaray.com/demo click on the Tangles work and see the images, but when you click again, it closes itself up.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `div.title` inside your work div and bind click event to `.title`. Enclose gallery in `div.gallery` and hide it by default.

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ewG9/)

Comment: Thanks for your demonstration, it actually works. But since i got a 1px border on the 'Work's bottom, it's crucial that it should also move down with the gallery too. If i apply that border to gallery, it's unfortunately hidden when not 'on'